# error when execution jboss cli script with properties

Tags: java, jboss, jboss-eap-6

As explained in https://access.redhat.com/solutions/321513 i am trying to use variable from properties file in a JBoss 6 CLI scripts but it's not working 
this is my script:

```
module add --name=com.oracle --resources=${oracleDriver} --dependencies=javax.api,javax.transaction.api

/subsystem=datasources/jdbc-driver=oracle:add(driver-name=oracle,driver-module-name=com.oracle,driver-xa-datasource-class-name=oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource)

data-source add --jndi-name=${appsdpeDSjndi} --name=${appsdpeDSname} --connection-url=${appsdpeDSurl} --driver-name=oracle --user-name=${appsdpeDSusername} --password=${appsdpeDSpassword}

data-source enable --name=${appsdpeDSjndi}
```

and  my properties file :

```
oracleDriver=C:\ojdbc8.jar
appsdpeDSname=appsdpeDS
appsdpeDSjndi=java:/jdbc/appsdpeDS
appsdpeDSurl=jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:XE
appsdpeDSusername=test
appsdpeDSpassword=test
```

the commande for executing the script :

jboss-cli.bat  --properties=C:\jbossCli\dataSourceParam.properties --file=C:\jbossCli\dataSource.cli
i get this error :
Failed to locate C:\JBoss\jboss-eap-6.4\bin\${oracleDriver}

Comment: What does your `jboss-cli.xml` file look like?

Comment: <resolve-parameter-values>true</resolve-parameter-values>

Comment: Did you ever fix this problem? =/